# CRUD module Play! 1.2.4

Tags: jpa, playframework, crud

I'm developing a webapp with Play! Framework (1.2.4). I've import CRUD module successfully, and connected a MySQL DB with JDBC.I've created a model like this:

```
@Entity

public class MyEntity extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String name;
    public String phone;
    public String web;
    public String address;

    public MyEntity (String name, String phone, String web, String address) {
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.web=web;
        this.address=address;
    }
}
```

In `localhost:9000/admin`, in Administration CRUD default panel, I try to Add a new object of MyEntity, doesn't works:

```
PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [models.MyEntity]

LogFail: object.save() (around line 152)
```

In my MySQL DB i have a table called MyEntity with 5 fields:

```
id INT (PK, NotNull, AUTO_INCREMENT);  
name VARCHAR;  
phone INT;  
web VARCHAR;  
address VARCHAR
```

Don't know why it doesn't works. I know JPA uses an autogenerated id field, but i want that autogenerated id will be MyEntity id field.

Log said:

```
[...]Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value.
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model already has an Id.

If you want to use your own Id then you should extend GenericModel instead.

Comment: Yeah, after many tests and searchs, now its fixed.

`@Entity
public class MyEntity extends GenericModel {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            public Long id;`