# Duplicated fields Hibernate + MySQL [Play 1.2.4]

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework

I have a MySQL model with 2 tables **Empresa** (Company) & **Ruta** (Route), `1:N` relationship between them. I'm using NetBeans for development.

Before running my app, in MySQL command line, I type:

```
describe ruta;
```

My table ruta has 3 fields:

```
idRuta  --  int(10) unsigned --  NONULL  --  PK  --  DEFAULTNULL  --  AUTOINC  
zona  --  varchar(45)  --  NO NULL  --  DEFAULTNULL --  
idEmpresa  -- int(11)  --  NONULL  --  KEYMUL  --  DEFAULTNULL
```

When I run my webapp, before add any object, log said:

```
[...]  
17:32:39,163 INFO  ~ Connected to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opticaDB  
17:32:41,021 ERROR ~ Unsuccessful: alter table Ruta add index FK270C1013017BBD (empresa_idEmpresa), add constraint FK270C1013017BBD foreign key (empresa_idEmpresa) references Empresa (idEmpresa)  
17:32:41,021 ERROR ~ Can't create table 'opticadb.#sql-b0c_10' (errno: 150)  
17:32:41,344 INFO  ~ Application 'Optica2.0' is now started !  
17:32:55,235 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000  
17:32:55,235 ERROR ~ Field 'idEmpresa' doesn't have a default value  
[...]
```

`idEmpresa` is **PK** of table **Empresa** and **FK** in table **Ruta**. Then, with my app running, when I type

```
describe ruta;
```

my table ruta has FOUR fields:

```
idRuta  --  int(10) unsigned --  NONULL  --  PK  --  DEFAULTNULL  --  AUTOINC  
zona  --  varchar(45)  --  NONULL  --  DEFAULTNULL --  
idEmpresa  -- int(11)  --  NONULL  --  KEYMUL  --  DEFAULTNULL 
empresa_idEmpresa  --  bigint(20)  --  YESNULL  --  DEFAULTNULL
```

My models are like this:

#### Model: Empresa

```
package models;    
import play.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import javax.persistence.*;  
import play.db.jpa.*;  
import play.data.validation.*;  
    
@Entity  
public class Empresa extends GenericModel {  
                
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    public Long idEmpresa;  
     
    public String nombre;  
    public Integer telefono;  
    public String web;  
    public String direccion;
  
    public String toString() {  
        return nombre;
    }  
}
```

#### Model: Ruta

```
package models;

import play.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class Ruta extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long idRuta;
    public String zona;

    @ManyToOne
    public Empresa empresa;
            
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return zona;
    }
}
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` instead of `play.db.jpa.Model`? If there is no particular reason, try `Model` and see if that works.

Comment: cause inheriting from .Model doesn't allow you to create your own @Id field. I asked it before, here you are:

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053253/crud-module-play-1-2-4[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happen usually if you have defined the table before the framework starts. It is **DDL generation pattern** feature feature and you can disabled it at `application.conf` file, and I suggest the value set to `jpa.ddl=none` while deploying the application on production mode.

As alternative, if you have defined your table before especially you have defined the foreign key. You should do something like this :

```
@Entity
public class Ruta extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long idRuta;
    public String zona;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idEmpresa")
    public Empresa empresa;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return zona;
    }
}
```

Note that, there is new annotation `@JoinColumn` that takes paramter `name` (the associate column name) at field `empresa`. See [this reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) for further read.

> #### UPDATE
>
> JPA DDL UPDATE **can't** delete or sometimes update your column automatically, if you have defined the table previously). As alternative, you can execute `ALTER TABLE` sql manually for that table or if you are in development mode, deleting the previous table is the simple way to do that.

Comment: thx iwawiwi, i used what you say but it doesn't work. @JoinColumn yes, but it doesn't solve the duplicate issue. I still having an extra column and don't know why

Comment: Okay, have you try to delete your table? I guess, you not do that yet. It is because, jpa ddl update cannot delete your column automatically. As alternative, you can execute alter table sql manually.

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks a lot iwa, i have been many days with this problem. I thought the cause was Play, not JPA. I used alter table drop column. Ok guys, solved!

Comment: Ok guys, I'm happy to know that your problem was resolved.. :) If this answer is useful. Please kindly to accept this answer by clicking accept sign.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use @JoinColumn to specify that you want to use the idEmpresa column to map the ManyToOne association:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idEmpresa")
public Empresa empresa;
```